# trigger an event to hosting WPF application from webbrowser control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF usercontrol that hosts an ASP.Net MVC Application using the webbrowser control.

I would like to notify the usercontrol when a certain action is performed on the WebApplication.
What are the possible ways to achieve this?

Comment: Can you modify the ASP.NET application? If yes, then you can set the browser control's `ObjectForScripting` property to an instance of a class which can be invoked by the site from JavaScript through `window.external`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Szabolcs Dézsi mentioned in the comment if you have the access to Web Application you can use `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting` to instance of an object and call its method from javascript. Here is a simple demo:

```
[ComVisible(true)] // Class must be ComVisible
public class Demo
{
    public void SayHello(string name) => MessageBox.Show($"Hello {name} !!!");
}
```

Create an instance of this class an assign it to `ObjectForScripting` property of the WebBrowser control:

```
webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new Demo();
```

and say this simple html page that we display in the `WebBrowser` control:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function sayhello()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            // the window.external is assigned an instance of 
            // class we created above.
            // We can call C# instance method SayHello directly.
            window.external.SayHello(name);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Say Hello" onclick="sayhello()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now whenever you fill a name and click SayHello button it will display MessageBox as expected.

**Also** you have the property `WebBrowser.Document` which an instance of `HtmlDocument` that lives in Microsoft HTML Object Library (MSHTML) Com Library, make sure to reference it in your project.

The Document property allows you query the DOM object of the current page and through it you can manipulate your html page like in javascript via Method exposed by `HtmlDocument` Class like `HtmlDocument.getElementById()` and many others.

for example this code modify the value attribute of name input from above html page after page is loaded by WebBrowser control:

```
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler((o, e) =>
{
    if (webBrowser.Document is HTMLDocument DOM)
    {
        var namefield = DOM.getElementById("name");
        namefield.setAttribute("value", "Enter your name!!!");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you to understand the power that `WebBrowser` control provides to manipulate loaded pages.

Comment: thats a very good explanation. Tried the same and works like a charm! Thank you!